# How to fix UnmodifiableLazyStringList

Tags: java

I have a `ProtocolStringList protoList`
And I try to remove item "None" from this list

```
List<String> list = protoList.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
list.remove("None");
```

Instead of I change the protoList into List, I still received an error like this

```
Error at com.google.protobuf.UnmodifiableLazyStringList$2.remove(UnmodifiableLazyStringList.java:180)
java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.remove(AbstractCollection.java:299)
```

Comment: Create a new list. Example: new ArrayList(protoList.stream().collect(Collectors.toList()))

Answer (score 2):

List is an interface and not every implementation of it is modifiable.

> Error at com.google.protobuf.**UnmodifiableLazyStringList**

If you want to get a list implementation that is modifiable (for example ArrayList) from a stream:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = (ArrayList<String>) protoList.stream().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
arrayList.remove("None");
```

Comment: I would suggest using the Interface (List<String>) for the definition of arrayList, then the cast would be unnecessary.
Also, instead of speculating on which JDK was used, you could ask the Poster to specify which JDK was used.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the JavaDoc for `Collectors#toList()`:

> There are no guarantees on the type, **mutability**,  serializability, or thread-safety of the `List` returned; if more flexibility is required, use `toCollection(Supplier)`

The OpenJDK implementation uses an `ArrayList`, which would be mutable. You seem to be using an exotic JVM implementation that uses `UnmodifiableLazyStringList` for `String`s?

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid to get the element in your `List` via `Stream#filter`

```
List<String> list = protoList.stream()
    .filter(s -> !"None".equals(s))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

AFAIK `Collectors#toList` provides an `ArrayList` (where it should be possible to remove elements) but you can't rely on it.
So avoid collecting all elements of a `Stream` into a `List` and then modify `List`.